# XSLT - Rename all childs of elements with specific attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the follwing XML document

```xml
<root>
  <List1 array="true">
    <Item>
      <Value1>405</Value1>
      <Value2>Text</Value2>
      <List2 array="true">
        <Item>123</Item>
        <Item>345</Item>
      </List2>
      <List3 array="true">
        <Item>
          <Value1>a</Value1>
          <Value2>b</Value2>
        </Item>
      </List3>
      <Value3>21956CB</Value3>
    </Item>
  </List1>
</root>
```

I want to rename all `<Item>` childs of the elements with an `array` attribute to the name of the parent. The target XML should look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <List1 array="true"/>
  <List1>
    <Value1>405</Value1>
    <Value2>Text</Value2>
    <List2 array="true"/>
    <List2>123</List2>
    <List2>345</List2>
    <List3 array="true"/>
    <List3>
      <Value1>a</Value1>
      <Value2>b</Value2>
    </List3>
    <Value3>21956CB</Value3>
  </List1>
</root>
```

My XSLT works just for the Items of the first element `<List1>`. The `<List2>` and `<List3>` will be ignore so that the result of my XSLTis:

**Wrong result:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <List1 array="true"/>
  <List1>
    <Value1>405</Value1>
    <Value2>Text</Value2>
    <List2 array="true">
      <Item>123</Item>
      <Item>345</Item>
    </List2>
    <List3 array="true">
      <Item>
        <Value1>a</Value1>
        <Value2>b</Value2>
      </Item>
    </List3>
    <Value3>21956CB</Value3>
  </List1>
</root>
```

**XSLT:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/xml" method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//*[@array]">

    <xsl:if test="count(./Item) = 1">
      <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:attribute name="array">true</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:for-each select="./Item">
      <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
        <xsl:choose>
          <!-- is the current node just a text without child then use just the text -->
          <xsl:when test="count(./*) = 0">
            <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <!-- otherwise copy all childs except the null values -->
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is wrong in my XSLT? My XSLT knowledge is not so good and I think I am missing something obvious.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT 2.0 stylesheet

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[@array]/Item">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="parent::*/name(.)"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's tested with Saxon HE/PE/EE 9.9.1.7. Here's an **explanation**:

**First** use the identity template to copy input unchanged to the output.

```xml
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Then** match all `<Item>` elements having a parent with an `@array` attribute, grab the element name of the parent, and use the name in a new element.

```xml
<xsl:template match="*[@array]/Item">
  <xsl:variable name="name" select="parent::*/name(.)"/>
  <xsl:element name="{$name}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```